# can i use fonts of google fonts for commercial use?

Tags: fonts, google

can i use fonts from google fonts for commercial use?
like logo design or flyer or brochure,etc

i have already entered the page named "Open Font License web version" but i still can't understand if i can use these fonts for other commercial designs like logos and flyer and social media designs.

i have seen some questions here but it's old and the license might be change, so i put another question.

Comment: If the license changes, you can just check at the google fonts website, there's no need to come back here to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The open source fonts in the Google Fonts catalog are published under licenses that allow you to use them on any website, whether it's commercial or personal.

https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq

Comment: thank you , but please read my question again ..